# external object text field length hard/soft limits

Tags: fields, lightning-connect

We're implementing a service cloud instance using external objects and odata 4.0.

One of the objects is a "file" object and holds information about downloadable files. One field holds the base64 value of the downloadable content and the max field length for this is 131,072 characters.

What's odd is that we're getting objects back from the odata service that are well over this length. We've successfully rendered downloadable content that have 500k characters, but we've noticed a file with 3 million characters does not render.

This makes it difficult to know where the actual limit is. Is there any documentation on Hard/Soft limits when it comes to external object field length?